# How to prove the Equivalence of two object of (proj1_sig f a) and (proj1_sig f b), where a and b are Equivalent

Tags: coq

I am trying to prove that given

`(eqX : relation X) (Hypo : Equivalence eqX) (f : X -> {x : X | P x})`

then

`eqX a b -> eqX (proj1_sig (f a)) (proj1_sig (f b))`

The function f get a parameter of Type X and give an existing assertion {x : X | P x}. ( for example `fun (n : nat) => {m : nat | S m = n}` )

In one word, I would like to show that given two parameters which are equivalent under the equivalent relation `eqX`, then the destruct result of existing assertion `{x : X | P x}` is also of the same equivalence class.

Can I prove this goal directly(which means the Specif.sig hold this property), or I should prove or claim that f satisfy some constraint and after which can I get this assertion proven.

Comment: I have trouble understanding the question. If `f` were of type `{x : A | P x}` then `proj1_sig f a` would be ill typed. Is the `respecting_equiv` theorem at the end the one you are trying to prove? What is the definition of `respecting`?

Comment: The respecting in Coq library is:
 `Definition respecting (eqa : Equivalence A (R : relation A),
                          eqb : Equivalence B (R' : relation B)) : Type :=
    { morph : A -> B | respectful R R' morph morph }.`

Comment: Sorry for the ill-formed problem before, the problem is edited to make the question clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Your claim is not directly provable; consider

```
X := nat
eqX a b := (a mod 2) = (b mod 2)
P a := True
f x := exist P (x / 2) I
```

Then we have `eqX 2 4` but we don't have `eqX (proj1_sig (f 2)) (proj1_sig (f 4))` because we don't have `eqX 1 2`.

You can either take in the theorem you are trying to prove as a hypothesis, or you can take in a hypothesis of type `forall a, proj1_sig (f a) = a`, or you can take in a hypothesis of type `forall a, eqX (proj1_sig (f a)) a`.  Note that all of these are provable (by `reflexivity` or `intros; assumption`) if you have `f a := exist P a (g a)` for some function `g`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to show?

```
Require Import Coq.Relations.Relation_Definitions.
Require Import Coq.Classes.Equivalence.
Require Import Setoid.
Generalizable All Variables.

Lemma foo `{!@Equivalence A RA, @Equivalence B RB, f : @respecting A _ _ B _ _ , @equiv A _ _ a b} :
  equiv (proj1_sig f a) (proj1_sig f b).
Proof.
now apply respecting_equiv.
Qed.
```